# Limiting scroll bar length

Tags: perl, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, perltk

I am trying to create a simple notepad like GUI using Perl Tk. I have used the **Scrolled** widget to create a **Text** widget with two scrollbars - one on the right and one on the bottom. The place where the two scrollbars meet looks like this:

[image]

However I would like to make it look like what is seen in the "Notepad" application by Microsoft. This is how I want it:

[image]

As you can see, there is a now an "empty square" where the two scrollbars meet. One more feature of notepad is that this "square" can be used to resize the window size. I want to be able to achieve the same.

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: You know, if you accept an answer once in a while, it make people more motivated to answer other questions you may have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick is to place the widgets with the `grid` geometry manager, which essentially creates an (uneven-sized) 4x4 grid with the text widget at "North-West", the vertical scrollbar at "North-East", the horizontal scrollbar at "South-West", and the empty square at "South-East".  There is a relevant example on the [man page](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm).

I think I'm allowed to quote the man page example as fair use (noting that it's Copyright © 1995-1997 Roger E. Critchlow Jr. Copyright © 1996 Sun Microsystems, Inc.).

```
# Make the widgets
toplevel .t
text .t.txt -wrap none -xscroll {.t.h set} -yscroll {.t.v set}
scrollbar .t.v -orient vertical   -command {.t.txt yview}
scrollbar .t.h -orient horizontal -command {.t.txt xview}

# Lay them out
grid .t.txt .t.v -sticky nsew
grid .t.h        -sticky nsew

# Tell the text widget to take all the extra room
grid rowconfigure    .t .t.txt -weight 1
grid columnconfigure .t .t.txt -weight 1
```

You'll have translate to Perl-Tk yourself, however.  There is some Perl-Tk-related discussion of grid (though not specifically about scrollbars) [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html) at TkDocs that might get you started.  The "Learning Perl/Tk" sample chapter [Geometry Management](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lperltk/chapter/ch02.html) also discusses `grid`.

Oh! You wanted a resizing control in the fourth square as well.  In Tcl/T(t)k, it's called a `ttk::sizegrip` and it's documented [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_sizegrip.htm).  I've never used it myself (as there are other ways to resize the window) and don't know if it's in Perl-Tk.  If it's not, there is a [wiki page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2988) discussing how to fake it (again, I've never tried that code myself).

Comment: `grid` is indeed _the_ way to solve this and the scrollbar problem is the original motivating use case; before it was invented, you had to do nasty tricks in `pack` with `frame`s as spacers, and it was really quite hard to get right.