# How to make a TableList scrollable in tcl?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm using the tablelist package to show a table list (heh) in a frame, but the frame is quite small and there is a bunch of columns in the table.

I need some way to make this tablelist scrollable both horizontally and vertically.

Here is the code of my tablelist

```
labelframe .t.lbf -text "Search Results for: $term" -padx 0 -width 47

tablelist::tablelist .t.mlb -selectmode multiple -columns {0 "File" 0 "Name" 0 "Version" 0 "Archtectures" 0 "Summary" 0 "Type"} -stretch all -background white -width 47                

pack .t.mlb  -in .t.lbf -anchor w

place .t.lbf -x 10 -y 125
```

Comment: I use the site of the person who created the tablelist for almost all the documentation I need. You can find out how to add scrollbars for example [here](http://www.nemethi.de/tablelist/tablelistWidget.html#std_options), plus many more options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted the basic recipe for adding scrollbars to a widget (in this case a text widget) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328952/limiting-scroll-bar-length/21330863#21330863). The following seems to work:

```
toplevel .t
labelframe .t.lbf -text "Search Results for: $term" -padx 0 -width 47
tablelist::tablelist .t.lbf.mlb -selectmode multiple -columns {0 "File" 0 "Name" 0 "Version" 0 "Archtectures" 0 "Summary" 0 "Type"} -stretch all -background white -width 47 -xscroll {.t.lbf.h set} -yscroll {.t.lbf.v set}

scrollbar .t.lbf.v -orient vertical   -command {.t.lbf.mlb yview}
scrollbar .t.lbf.h -orient horizontal -command {.t.lbf.mlb xview}

# Lay them out
grid .t.lbf -sticky nsew

grid .t.lbf.mlb .t.lbf.v -sticky nsew
grid .t.lbf.h            -sticky nsew

# Tell the tablelist widget to take all the extra room
grid rowconfigure    .t.lbf .t.lbf.mlb -weight 1
grid columnconfigure .t.lbf .t.lbf.mlb -weight 1

place .t.lbf -x 10 -y 125
```

Note to other readers: the OP wanted to wrap the `tablelist` in a `labelframe` and then `place` that. Without those requirements, the task gets somewhat easier. Again, see my example in the link above: reusing it for a table list only involves replacing the text widget.

Documentation: [grid](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/grid.htm), [labelframe](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/labelframe.htm), [place](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/place.htm), [scrollbar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/scrollbar.htm), [toplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/toplevel.htm)

Comment: @LucasOliveira: simplified it a bit by taking out the `t.frm` frame, which became unnecessary once I gave up on packing it inside the labelframe. The new code seems to work equally well.